# Django custom login form does not validate

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have implemented a custom user model in my django project. I can use it to register a user however I cannot use it to login. It fails to validate against the is_valid() function. I have been able to confirm the email & password values are being passed through to views.py but the form is not being validated

Here is my login view code

```
def login_view(request):
    context = {}
    if request.POST:
        form = UserLoginForm(data = request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = request.POST['email']
            password = request.POST['password']
            
            print(email)
            print(password)

            user = authenticate(request, email=email,password=password)

            print(user)

            if user is not None:
                login(request,user)
                return redirect("logistics:dashboard")
    else:
        print('form not valid')
        form = UserLoginForm()
        context["loginform"] = form

    return render(request, 'dashboard/authentication-login.html', context)
```

This is login form code

```
class UserLoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(label="Password", widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'password')

        widgets = {
            'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'password': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }

        def clean(self):
            if self.is_valid():
                email = self.clean_data['email']
                pasword = self.clean_data['password']

            if not authenticate(email=email, pasword=pasword):
                raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid Credentials")
```

Comment: Can you also share how you *register* users. Do you use a custom user model? If yes, share the user model and manager.

Answer (score 0):

Its bcs you actually using
`email = request.POST['email'] password = request.POST['password']`
When you already have data in your form `UserLoginForm=(request.POST)` by request.POST

Change it to this:

```
form = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid():
    email = form.cleaned_data['email']
    password = form.cleaned_data['password']

    print(email)
    print(password)

    user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)
    # and mb change your authenticate there to that but im not sure         
    # user = authenticate(email=email.strip(),
    #                password=password.strip())

    login(request, user)
    return redirect("logistics:dashboard")
 return render(request, 'your_template.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')

        if email and password:
            user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
            if not user:
                raise forms.ValidationError('Invalid email or password')
        return super(UserLoginForm, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I have changed it to that and it still is not valid

Comment: Can you share stacktrace?

Comment: and mb try ```REQUIRED_FIELDS = []``` in your user model

Comment: And i`ll update my answer change your form as well

Comment: I have found a way to fix it.

Comment: I changed ```UserLoginForm(forms.ModelForm):``` to ```UserLoginForm(AuthenticationForm):``` and changed this field ```email = request.POST['email']``` to ```  email = request.POST['username'] ```

Answer (score 0):

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    email = cleaned_data.get('email')
    password = cleaned_data.get('password')

    if email and password:
        if not authenticate(email=email, password=password):
            raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid Credentials")

    return cleaned_data
```

You can use clean method to return the cleaned data.